# Using external table to iteratively change parameters into ArcPy code

Tags: python, arcpy, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Python 2.7 and ArcPy under Jupyter notebook environment. I would like to adapt iteratively my code to a reference table.

This is my reference table which contains the 3 variables that I use for the tool I am running in ArcPy:

```
RegY          HunCal    CRY
    1            1718     BL1
    1            1112     JU1
    1            1112     JU1
    1            1213     JU1
```

This is a simple XLS table which I imported to my Jupyter notebook. I have it as a visual reference for when I have to change these variables in my code.

In the beginning, I was doing it by hand because they were a few changes to make. But now there are more than 150 changes to adapt, and, this amount increases with time. Therefore, I would like to modify the code in such a way that it uses the reference table to iterate through every feature each time the reference table changes.

This is the code I am using:

```
# 2011
# Set geoprocessor object property to overwrite existing output
arcpy.gp.overwriteOutput = True


arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\GeoData\simSear\SBA_D.gdb'
    
# Process: Group Similar Features  
SS.SimilaritySearch("redD_RegY_1_1112","blackD_CRY_JU1_1112","SS_JU1_1112","NO_COLLAPSE",
                        "MOST_SIMILAR","ATTRIBUTE_PROFILES",0,
                        "Temperatur;Precipitat", 'DateFin')
```

How can I adapt the code in such a way that the variables from the reference table are inserted into my code in the following way?

From the reference table, the values from `RegY` would be replaced in `redD_RegY_**1**_1112`. The values from `CRY` would be replaced in `blackD_CRY_**JU1**_1112` and `SS_**JU1**_1112` and finally, the values from `HunCal` would be replaced in `redD_RegY_1_**1112**`, `blackD_CRY_JU1_**1112**`,`SS_JU1_**1112**`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a view of the excel table using Make table view
2. Read the values row by row with da.SearchCursor
3. With [string format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) construct the input parameters strings

Something like:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(in_table=r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\excelfile123.xls\Sheet1$', out_view='tempview')
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('tempview', ['RegY', 'HunCal', 'CRY']) as cursor: #Adjust field names to match your data
    for regy, huncal, cry in cursor:
        S.SimilaritySearch("redD_RegY_{0}_1112".format(regy),"blackD_CRY_{0}_1112".format(cry), ... Dont know exactly what you want
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @BERA, thank you for your input. I think I am getting closer. However I am getting an error: The excel sheet has 2 fields declared as integers (RegY and HunCal) but when these two are getting printed into the code, they are transformed as decimals, for example, instead of being printed like **redD_RegY_1_1718**, it is printed as **redD_RegY_1.0_1718.0**.  I checked the excel and these two fields are declared as integers, not decimals. Do you have any idea why at the time of using the tool `MakeTableView_management`, this transformation occurs?

Comment: Thank you @BERA, this code works phenomenally. I had to give an extra treatment to the excel table, because for some reason, the data type of the fields changed when imported. Afterwards, it works great!